# Meteor.js Handlebars template logic operators

Tags: operators, meteor, handlebars.js

From [this page](http://doginthehat.com.au/2012/02/comparison-block-helper-for-handlebars-templates/), I inserted to my /client/helpers/handlebars.js file this handlebars helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('compare', function (lvalue, operator, rvalue, options) {

var operators, result;

if (arguments.length < 3) {
    throw new Error("Handlerbars Helper 'compare' needs 2 parameters");
}

if (options === undefined) {
    options = rvalue;
    rvalue = operator;
    operator = "===";
}

operators = {
    '==': function (l, r) { return l == r; },
    '===': function (l, r) { return l === r; },
    '!=': function (l, r) { return l != r; },
    '!==': function (l, r) { return l !== r; },
    '<': function (l, r) { return l < r; },
    '>': function (l, r) { return l > r; },
    '<=': function (l, r) { return l <= r; },
    '>=': function (l, r) { return l >= r; },
    'typeof': function (l, r) { return typeof l == r; }
};

if (!operators[operator]) {
    throw new Error("Handlerbars Helper 'compare' doesn't know the operator " + operator);
}

result = operators[operator](lvalue, rvalue);

if (result) {
    return options.fn(this);
} else {
    return options.inverse(this);
}

});
```

And to the template:

```
{{#compare "Test" "Test"}}
Default comparison of "==="
{{/compare}}
```

And in console I always see: Exception from Deps recompute: Error: Handlerbars Helper 'compare' needs 2 parameters

I tried this as well:

```
{{#compare "Test" "==" "Test"}}
```

But this did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
{{#compare "Test" "Test" operator="=="}}
```

Comment: Perhaps that snippet of code has a couple of issues. Have a look at the smartpackage over at https://github.com/raix/Meteor-handlebar-helpers, it also has a couple of extra features which are really cool :)

Comment: ok i will look at it. But its very weird the code does not work isnt? Or have you tried it?