# spacebars: how to use and / or in if statements

Tags: meteor, spacebars

I have following code:

```
 <div class="form-group {{#if afFieldIsInvalid name='latitude' OR name='longitude'}}has-error{{/if}}">......</div>
```

How can I use AND/OR in if conditions of spacebars templates ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Meteor.js Handlebars template logic operators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252750/meteor-js-handlebars-template-logic-operators)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spacebars is an extension of Handlebars, which is designed to be a logic-less template language.

The solution is to register a helper. For the general case, see these similar questions:

- [How to do IF logic in HandleBars templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18965083/how-to-do-if-logic-in-handlebars-templates)
- [Include conditional logic in Handlebars templates, or just use javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17454624/include-conditional-logic-in-handlebars-templates-or-just-use-javascript)
- [boolean logic within a handlebars template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14839375/boolean-logic-within-a-handlebars-template)

To define helpers in Meteor, use [`Template.registerHelper`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_registerhelper)

Answer (score 10):

Spacebars can't handle logical expressions, so you need to create a helper handling the calculations for you.

Actually, you can achieve `and` functionality with nested ifs like this:

```html
{{#if condition1}}
    {{#if condition2}}
        <p>Both condition hold!</p>
    {{/if}}
{{/if}}
```

And `or` like this:

```html
{{#if condition1}}
    <p>One of the conditions are true!</p>
{{else}}
    {{#if condition2}}
        <p>One of the conditions are true!</p>
    {{/if}}
{{/if}}
```

But I would prefer using a helper.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extension designed for this case.

[Raix Handlebars](https://github.com/raix/Meteor-handlebar-helpers)

You can use for an 'AND' condition something like this:

```
{{#if $in yourVariable 'case1' 'case2' }}
      Your code Here
{{/if}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking the solution one step further.  This adds the compare operator.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('ifCond', function (v1, operator, v2, options) {

    switch (operator) {
        case '==':
            return (v1 == v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
        case '===':
            return (v1 === v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
        case '!=':
            return (v1 != v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
        case '!==':
            return (v1 !== v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
        case '<':
            return (v1 < v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
        case '<=':
            return (v1 <= v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
        case '>':
            return (v1 > v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
        case '>=':
            return (v1 >= v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
        case '&&':
            return (v1 && v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
        case '||':
            return (v1 || v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
        default:
            return options.inverse(this);
    }
});
```

Use it in a template like this:

```
{{#ifCond name='latitude' '||' name='longitude'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using if-else syntax

```
<div class="form-group {{#if afFieldIsInvalid}} latitude {{else}} longitude {{/if}} has-error">...</div>
```

Answer (score -6):

instead of using 'OR' try '||'.
Or define a method in a javascript file.