# How to use and condition in if statement on meteor template?

Tags: meteor

I want to use the and condition in if statement like

```
{{#if requiredExp equals 0 and tile equals "SSE"}}
Expierince cannot be  equal to 0
{{/if}}
```

How to write this condition using and in meteor template?

Comment: Note that you can use nesting of template conditionals as well as inverting the logic. Your first condition can be expressed as `{{#unless requiredExp}}` as long as all other possible values of `requiredExp` are *true.* The string comparison in the second condition needs a helper however.

Comment: I answered same question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28426843/spacebars-how-to-use-and-or-in-if-statements/40736986#40736986).

Answer (score 2):

Meteor is designed in a way that you can't put logic in your templates. You can create a simple helper like equals, but you cannot use logic operators like && and || in templates because this logic does not belong to templates.

You could create a global [template helper](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_registerhelper) equals for this:

```
Template.registerHelper('equals', function(param1, param2) {
  return param1 === param2;
});
```

So you can use it in your templates:

```
{{#if equals requiredExp 0}}
  {{#if equals tile "SSE"}} 
    Expierince cannot be equal to 0 
  {{/if}}
{{/if}}
```

Or, the better option is to create a helper that handles the logic you want:

```
Template.yourTemplateName.helpers({
  showExperienceNotification: function() {
    return this.requiredExp === 0 && this.tile === 'SSE';
  }
});
```

And use it in your template:

```
<template name="yourTemplateName">
  {{#if showExperienceNotification}}
    Experience cannot be equal to 0
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

You can access template data via keyword `this` in your helper:
`this.requiredExp` and `this.tile`. Read more about Meteor templates and data context: https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/a-guide-to-meteor-templates-data-contexts/